# Where do Linux daemons store their data files?

Tags: linux, service

We know, that normal applications store their (user-specific) data under:

```
/home/<user>/.<application>/
```

Where do Linux daemons (services) store their data files ?
Where goes data of ssh, thermald, wpa_supplicant, snapd etc. ?

Comment: Where they want, usually at `/etc/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable data files are stored under `/var`. It is beyond the scope of an SE answer to describe the various sub-directories and the uses that the programmer and administrator of a daemon may make of them.

[Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard version 3, section 5.1](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05.html#purpose31%20Linux%20Filesystem%20Hierarchy%20Standard%20v3%20Ch5) says

> /var contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files.